# Why isn't the TypeScript compiler smart enough to avoid "implicit any" errors from importing a JSON object?

Tags: json, typescript

Consider the following short code snippet:

emojis.json:

```
{
    "grinning": "",
    "grimacing": "",
    "grin": ""
}
```

emoji.ts:

```
import emojis from './emojis.json';

function printEmoji(emojiName: string) {
    if (emojiName in emojis) {
        console.log(emojis[emojiName]);
    }
}
```

This successfully compiles with the following command:

`npx tsc emoji.ts --resolveJsonModule --esModuleInterop`

However, the following command fails:

`npx tsc emoji.ts --resolveJsonModule --esModuleInterop --strict`

Giving the following error:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ "grinning": string; "grimacing": string; "grin": string; }'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ "grinning": string; "grimacing": string; "grin": string; }'.
```

From my research elsewhere, I see that I can prevent this error by inserting the following ugly-looking code:

```
export type Emoji = keyof typeof emojis;
function isKeyof<T extends object>(obj: T, possibleKey: keyof any): possibleKey is keyof T {
    return possibleKey in obj;
}
function printEmoji(emojiName: string) {
    if (isKeyof(emojis, emojiName)) {
        console.log(emojis[emojiName]);
    }
}
```

Or, alternatively, the following code will also prevent the error (and is slightly more compact):

```
function printEmoji(emojiName: string) {
    const emoji = (emojis as { [key: string]: string })[emojiName];
    if (emoji) {
        console.log(emoji);
    }
}
```

However, it strikes me that this should be unnecessary. Shouldn't the TypeScript compiler be smart enough to statically read the "emojis.json" file and determine that the above code block is safe with just checking via the `in` operator or `Object.keys()`? Is this a bug in the TypeScript compiler?

Comment: You can type `emojis` as `{ [key: string]: string }`. Otherwise you need the [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards).

Comment: Wait, why are you writing `emojiName in Object.keys(emojis)` instead of `emojiName in emojis`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Can you give a quick example of how to type it like that? I'm new to TypeScript and not following.

Comment: @jcalz You're right - the `Object.keys()` is unnecessary. I've edited the question now, thanks.

Comment: An object (to the TS compiler with noImplicitAny) is not simply a bag of random properties, and `emojiName` could be any string not just `grinning | grin | grimacing`. The reason it can't just assume that the `in` operator is sufficient is that types are checked statically but the set of object keys can be altered at runtime. The `in` check by itself can't assure the compiler that `emojiName` is a member of the set of statically verified keys, which is why you need the 'ridiculous' code in the type guard function.

Comment: @JaredSmith I'm still not following. If at runtime, 'poop' was added dynamically to the list of keys, then wouldn't the `in` operator still be good enough to ensure that no error will occur?

Comment: @James sure, *at runtime*. Types are checked at *compile time*. The type checker has to be pessimistic about what *might* happen at runtime, because it has no way of knowing unless you explicitly code it. You could use a literal string that's a static key of the object like "grinning", or you could cast it to such, but it can't simply infer that it's ok.

Comment: See [microsoft/TypeScript#31445](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31445) and [microsoft/TypeScript#34867](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34867); the compiler takes `key in obj` and narrows the type of `obj`, but not the type of `key`.  The "ridiculous"/"ugly" user-defined type guard is the best way to ask for key narrowing currently.  Good luck!